# Numpy asarray wraps list() around list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have lists in lists which I'm trying to convert to a numpy array, however it's wrapping list() around each element.

This means I get errors like "IndexError: too many indices for array" when trying to slice it.

```
list = f()
print(list)
np_array = np.asarray(list)
print(np_array)
```

Output:

```
[[0,5,2,5,5,4,5],[1,0,5,2,2,3,4],[2,5,3,4,8,5,2]]

list([0,5,2,5,5,4,5])
list([1,0,5,2,2,3,4])
list([2,5,3,4,8,5,2])
```

I'm expecting the results to look like;

```
[[0,5,2,5,5,4,5],[1,0,5,2,2,3,4],[2,5,3,4,8,5,2]]

[0,5,2,5,5,4,5]
[1,0,5,2,2,3,4]
[2,5,3,4,8,5,2]
```

Comment: Your outcome happens when your lists don't have the same length. They have to have the same length if you want a well-behaved numpy array

Comment: Thanks, you're right bug in creating the list